# __env :-Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services

I was trying to deploy angular node app on aws beanstalk by this blog https://blog.devgenius.io/deploy-angular-nodejs-application-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-9ab13076a736

So initially I created the folder environments under the assets folder. Added `env.js` file to the environments folder and added the following code in there:

```
(function (window) {
   window.__env = window.__env || {};
   window.__env.SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
}(this));
```

Then I added

```
 <script src=”/assets/environments/env.js”></script>
```

script to the `index.html` file.

I then added the following to `environment.ts` file and `environment.prod.ts` files:

```
server_URL: window['__env']['SERVER_URL']
```

I then got the following error with `__env`:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows something different than what you posted. `env` vs `__env`

Answer (score 2):

Using `suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors` is quite a drastic approach. It is recommended to use a `@ts-ignore` comment instead:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  // @ts-ignore
  server_URL: window["env"]["SERVER_URL"]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript can use an implicit type for the window object. The default angular configuration will respect that type when building.

You can extend the window type by adding the following on top of the class to use your `__env` variable (I recommend you do this option):

```
declare global {
  interface YourWindow = Window & { '__env': any; }
}

...

server_URL: (window as YourWindow)['__env']['SERVER_URL']
```

You could also modify your `tsconfig.json` file to be [more permissive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors.html):

```
{
  ...
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
}
```

Comment: ... but surely there must be a way to fix the error without losing type checking.

Comment: @DavidKnipe that's the first option in my answer...

Comment: But isn't there a standard type file for Window objects that you could import? Then you'd get a much more accurate type declaration on `window`.

Comment: no standard type will have the OP's `__env` variable on it...

Comment: Then how about something like `type MyWindow = Window & { '__env': any; };`? Or, better yet, add more details such as `Window & { '__env': { SERVER_URL: string } }`

Comment: I like it, updated. There might be other variables on env, so I would not suggest the type for their variable. This will get them going